# Available Prism Region controls

Tags: wpf, controls, prism

I'm new to Prism, and I tend to just do as in the samples I see; place the Regions inside an *ItemsControl*. I have read that more controls can be used for defining region, but not all. However, I haven't seen an overview on what controls can be used to define Prism regions and not. Is there a rule or a list to it?

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="MainRegion" Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from the [documentation for "UI Composition"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458944.aspx) in the Composite Application Library:

> Composite Application Library provides
>   the following region adapters:
>   `ContentControlRegionAdapter`,
>   `SelectorRegionAdapter`, and
>   `ItemsControlRegionAdapter`. These
>   adapters are meant to adapt controls
>   derived from `ContentControl`,
>   `Selector`, and `ItemsControl`,
>   respectively. There is an additional
>   adapter, `TabControlRegionAdapter`, used
>   in Silverlight because the Tab control
>   does not derive from `Selector` as in
>   WPF.

So, the game here in a nutshell is that these adapters work for any control that *derives* from these supported containers.  For example, a `TabControl` inherits from `Selector`.

This is obviously not the limit.  If you have a custom control that doesn't inherit from one of these controls, you can implement your own Region Adapter to support that control.

Hope this helps,
Anderson